# Time Remaining in file downloading with NSURLRequest in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsurlrequest

I am working on downloading in my app, I have add the functionality like file downloaded size and Total size, but have no idea how to manage the time remaining to complete this process. Can anybody help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate the time remaining by computing the average transfer rate so far (number of bytes received / elapsed time) and applying that to the number of bytes remaining.

Within your `NSURLConnectionDelegate`'s implementation of `-connection:didReceiveResponse:` you'll want to record the time at which the transfer started and the expected size of the response (`-[NSURLResponse expectedContentLength]`). Then as you receive chunks of data via `-connection:didReceiveData:` you can keep track of the number of bytes of data received. That will give you sufficient information to estimate the time remaning as outlined above.

Comment: Note, depending upon your server, you may or may not receive an `expectedContentLength`.